# Reordering items in mobilesafari

Tags: jquery, iphone, drag-and-drop, mobile-safari

After searching around i still have no clue about the best practice to reorder a set of items in mobile safari. I'm currently using, in the desktop version of my webapplication, jQuery sortable function applied to a set of table rows, with an ajax callback to update items positioning.

What would be the best way of doing this in mobile safari through jquery or plain javascript? The table is longer then the screen, so also the normal scrolling should be present.

Other approaches that are usable and do not make use of drag and dropping are also welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From an interface point of view, for Mobile Safari instead of drag and drop you could present the user a list of the items with up and down arrows next to each item. Depending on which arrow the user clicks, it moves the item up or down.

There are plugins for jQuery that handle touch versions of drag and drop :  [view demo](http://www.stevefenton.co.uk/cmsfiles/assets/File/mobiledragdrop.html)